# Google dataflow workflow error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a batch read and write to a storage bucket within the same project. Im see this exception when is trying to write the output. any idea?

```
(c1a5d1aff2d8459b): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "No object name",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "No object name"
}
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:508)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:123)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:220)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:170)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:172)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the job ID?

Comment: "2017-04-19_10_45_04-17412713462337636976"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by specifying an incorrect path to `TextIO.Write` (missing the GCS bucket - an example correct path is `gs://some-bucket/some-output-prefix` whereas in this job it was specified as simply `gs://some-output-prefix`).

This should have been caught at pipeline construction time, before starting the workers. This is a bug in Apache Beam and Dataflow SDK's validation of GCS paths. I'm working on a fix at http://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2602, follow that PR for updates. – jkff 10 mins ago